# node-canvas layers replacement

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-canvas

I have this image, that is white, but there is some black text on it (and a square), and I want to replace the white with another image. How do I do this in node-canvas? I checked out the documentation but there isn't a layer feature, so how can I accomplish that without layers?

I also don't want to use `applyText` or anything like that because I've already got all the images done :/.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm new to canvas (haven't used the HTML5 canvas either), the only thing I tried was drawing the backgrond image before the "almost white" image, which did not work (obviously).